# Google Places api - how to influence the selection for better results?

Tags: google-places-api

I'm testing Google Places API to retrieve the most popular tourist attraction in some locations. I can retrieve up to 60 results by using the pagination but in the results I get, I'm missing some major attractions while I did not reach the limit of 60 results and some minor attractions were available.

I use PHP to call the API and my API call uses the following URL structure:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?type=tourist_attraction|point_of_interest|landmark|natural_feature|museum|amusement_park|park&language=fr&key=***myapi***&query=***location***
```

If I use Brussels as location, it returns only 20 results while there are way more results available for Brussels when looking for tourist attraction directly on the map. Some of the most popular attractions are not even displayed in the results. I have many similar cases for other cities/location, it's like the search was looking for results in a too narrow area.

Is there a way to get more results? Or do a kind of radius search to go around the narrow results provided by the api?

Query example:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?type=tourist_attraction&language=fr&key=XXX&query=bruxelles

Places returned: 20
If I use pagination to get to page 2 and 3, it basically returns results that are already in the first page and I end up with 20 different places.

Places found:
Atomium,Grand-Place,Manneken Pis,Palais du Coudenberg,Parc du Cinquantenaire,Mont des Arts,Cathédrale des Sts Michel et Gudule, Bruxelles,Mini-Europe,Musée de la ville de Bruxelles,Monument du Cinquantenaire,Place Royale Bruxelles,Centre Belge de la Bande Dessinée,Parc de Bruxelles,Tour Noire,Colonne du Congrès,Tour Anneessens,Musées Royaux des Beaux-Arts de Belgique,Parc Léopold,Basilique Nationale du Sacré-Cœur à Koekelberg, Église Notre-Dame des Victoires au Sablon

There are a couple of big tourist attractions that are not in this list while I see them on Google Maps when searching for tourist attraction in Brussels.

Example:
Royal Palace (11k reviews), Train World (5k reviews), Horta Museum (2k reviews), Autoworld (7k reviews), Magritte Museum (5k reviews), St Hubert galleries (32k reviews),...

In the list of places coming from the api there are popular tourist attractions but some of them are way less popular in terms of reviews than some of the ones that are missing. They are all in the category "tourist_attraction".

So I don't understand why I only get those ones while there are many others.

Thanks

Laurent

Comment: How about reading the docs? *`type`: Restricts the results to places matching the specified type. Only one type may be specified. If more than one type is provided, all types following the first entry are ignored.*

Comment: @MrUpsidown one type or multiple types end up with the same problem. I used multiple types as an alternative after reading a couple of suggestions on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Obviously yes, if your first **and/or** only type is `tourist_attraction` then all other types are ignored, as the docs says. You should provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue. That means an example request (with real coordinates), an example response and example points of interest that you believe should be in the response and which are not. Otherwise it's just impossible to help/debug.

Comment: @MrUpsidown fair enough, I have added an examples and compared places with Google Maps.

Answer (score 0):

You *might* get better results from [Place Nearby Search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby), with some caveats.

Results are [ranked by `prominence` by default](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby#rankby): *Ranking will favor prominent places within the set radius over nearby places that match but that are less prominent. Prominence can be affected by a place's ranking in Google's index, global popularity, and other factors. When prominence is specified, the radius parameter is required.*

Example:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?radius=10000&type=tourist_attraction&location=50.847642,4.35717

To find the **nearest** results to a given location, use [`rankby=distance`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby#rankby) (**without** `radius`) and `type=tourist_attraction` (**only one** type).

Example: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?rankby=distance&type=tourist_attraction&location=50.847642,4.35717

**Caveats**:

- This method is called **Nearby** Search for a reason: it only returns results that are *near* to the given location, if the only results that match the given `type` are far away they won't be returned.
- The region where results are returns (search radius) is *adjusted dynamically based on area density, independent of `rankby` parameter*, so might still get less than 60 results in some places.